# Android Market Publishing Issues

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

I have an app which I have just updated to froyo to take advantage of 
the move to SD card feature. I am now trying to upload the update to 
the market but I keep getting the following error: "The file is 
invalid: W/ResourceType( 7193): Bad string block: last string is not 0- 
terminated ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a 
string value". I changed the value in the manifest from 
"android:label="@string/app_name" " to "android:label="test" " and 
uploaded it, then it started complaining about the icon, saying that 
it wasn't a string. Anyone have any ideas? 
The application part of my manifest is shown below and I'm properly 
confused. The app compiles into an APK, it even installs and runs fine 
on my N1 (installing from SD card) it just won't upload to the market. 
 
         
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have absolutely no idea 
what's wrong, seems like I've tried everything I can think of 
including re-installing eclipse. 
Cheers 
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Did you run zipalign against it?

If you right click on your project in eclipse, you can go to Android tools, then export signed Application Package. This does the zipalign and walks you through the signing process.

EDIT: 
Please try defining all of your resources - it appears that some/all of your string/icon/etc resources have not been defined. Eclipse takes care of all of these things under normal circumstances, so I'm not sure what led up to this situation?

Comment: Yes, I've exported it like that as It uses the maps API I needed the Key. Still no joy though :(