# ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Tags: android, google-play

I have this error "ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value" when trying to publish my application to android market.
Some time ago this app was already published successfully on market, but when I apply minor changes in AndroidManifest.xml (changing versionCode and versionName) I get this error constantly.

I looked to all similar topics here, such as:

[Android Market Publishing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915001/android-market-publishing-issues)

["ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value" when trying to upload to the Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474526/error-getting-androidicon-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value-when-tr)

[The file is invalid: ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588718/the-file-is-invalid-error-getting-androidname-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-s)

but none of these solution helped me. Do you know any other reason of such an error?
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.samsung.att.deskhome" android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="2.3"> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/mainmenu_icon_homemount" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".CradleMain" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:launchMode="singleTask" >
<meta-data android:name="android.dock_home" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>     
<activity android:name=".CradleHomeSettings" android:label="@string/cradle_home_settings" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".CradleWeatherSettings" android:label="@string/cradle_weather_settings" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".CradleWallpaperChooser" android:label="@string/pick_wallpaper" android:screenOrientation="nosensor" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true" android:configChanges="locale">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: The reason of the issue was that values/strings.xml didn't contain one of the "android:label" attributes, though it was in other localized strings.xml.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you get an error from the play store while uploading make sure to execute that same command locally to get proper output. The output retrieved from the online console is misleading.

An example from my own code, this is what I got on the online console:

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType( 4560): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0601c6 (t=5 e=454) in package 0 (error -75)
ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

And a local run of that same tool (found at build-tools in sdk dir)

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/your/apk
```

revealed useful information like the position where the check failed:

```
package: name='X' versionCode='X' versionName='X'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'17'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
...
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
application-label:'Photo Tools'
application-label-zh:'摄影工具'
application-label-nl:'Photo Tools'
application-label-fr:'Photo Tools'
application-label-es:'Photo Tools'
application-label-it:'Photo Tools'
application-label-ru:'Photo Tools'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable/phototools_icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable/phototools_icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable/phototools_icon.png'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable/phototools_icon.png'
application: label='Photo Tools' icon='res/drawable/phototools_icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='be.hcpl.android.phototools.PhotoToolsActivity'  label='Photo Tools' icon=''
W/ResourceType(30945): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0601c6 (t=5 e=454) in package 0 (error -84)
ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

Comment: I get the same error, your answer is missing the solution, what did you do after you get this dump

Comment: @meda for me a string value was missing on the default strings.xml while translated in another strings.xml file

Answer (score 1):

To investigate, I followed the following methodology:

1. comment out the activities one by one
2. build the signed release
3. run aapt dump badging /path/to/your/apk
4. see errors and repeat

This allowed me to narrow down to the root the of my problem. Just a string without resource instead the label was not being used in the app. I removed the label attribute as a fix.

Answer (score 1):

read @hcpl answer, if you cannot finsd the error look for the next activity listed in manifest. in his post:

```
launchable-activity: name='be.hcpl.android.phototools.PhotoToolsActivity'  label='Photo Tools' icon=''
W/ResourceType(30945): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0601c6 (t=5 e=454) in package 0 (error -84)
ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

You might think the problem is related to `PhotoToolsActivity` but it is about the next activity which does not get log because it `aapt` crashes

Answer (score 0):

Check the values/strings.xml and values-xx/strings.xml
You should be sure that everyone word in values/strings.xml must have corresponding word under values-xx/strings.xml .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the default string.xml was missing, accidentally deleted from the project.

I use:

```
disable 'ExtraTranslation'
disable 'MissingTranslation'
```

in the gradle, so I've no evidence of the missing string.xml file.